# How to add subfolders to all folders of a directory?

Tags: vba, outlook, directory

I'm organizing e-mail in Outlook 2016. I need to create three subfolders in each folder.

I have code to create the three subfolders in each folder:

```vb
Public Sub CreateFolders()
    Dim CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim List As New VBA.Collection
    Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    List.Add Array("1", olFolderInbox)
    List.Add Array("2", olFolderInbox)
    List.Add Array("3", olFolderInbox)
    
    Set CurrentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set Folders = CurrentFolder.Folders
    For Each Item In List
        Folders.Add Item(0), Item(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

I got it from https://www.computergaga.com/blog/loop-through-subfolders-using-filesystemobject/

How do I create the three subfolders in all folders of a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Sub I use to loop through all subfolders, it just calls the sub for each new subfolder and then loops through the sub-sub folders then the sub-sub-sub folders etc.:

```
Public Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folder As object)

    For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
        LoopAllSubFolders subfolder 'remove this if you only want to add the folders to the first subfolder
        'do stuff with folders, example: subfolder.Name = "this is a file.exe"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I´ve tried to integrate it into my code but nothing works, it either doesn't loop or it returns an error. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I think the issue may be that you are using code (including my code) that is intended for file system files. If my assumption is correct you are  trying to manipulate the folders used to store email inside outlook?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I'm trying to do. I'll take a look at these resources and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that the `For Each` goes wrong as you add to folder.SubFolders what changes the Folders collection. I ran into this with moving items. Use `For n = LBound(folder.SubFolders) To Ubound(folder.SubFolders) -1 : LoopAllSubFolder. Folder.Subfolders` to avoid.

Comment: Hi, could you show me how to integrate the snippet into the code I already have? I've tried several ways but it always returns a "needs object" prompt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to manipulate the folders **Inside** Outlook, like I now suspect, then I would look at these resources for answers (as I am unfamiliar with this):

### Library on methods, properties etc for these folders:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210948(v=office.11)

### Some code examples:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20301462/Setting-MAPIfolder-properties-in-Outlook's-VBA.html

Answer (score 0):

This should be flexible enough to generate folders wherever needed.

```vb
Public Sub CreateSubFolders_Recursively()

    Dim parentFolder As folder
    Dim firstLevelSubfolder As folder
    Dim firstLevelSubfolders As Folders
    
    Dim list As New VBA.Collection
        
    list.Add Array("1", olFolderInbox)
    list.Add Array("2", olFolderInbox)
    list.Add Array("3", olFolderInbox)
    
    Set parentFolder = ActiveExplorer.currentFolder
    Debug.Print "parentFolder: " & parentFolder
    
    ' To create the list in parentFolder
    CreateFoldersParent parentFolder, list
    
    ' To create the liat in folders under parentFolder
    LoopAllSubFolders parentFolder, list
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub


Private Sub CreateFoldersParent(currentFolder As folder, list As VBA.Collection)

    Dim subFolder As folder
    Dim firstLevelSubfolders As Folders
    
    Dim arrItem As Variant
    
    For Each arrItem In list
            
        Debug.Print arrItem(0)
        Set subFolder = Nothing
                
        ' Bypass expected error if the folder already exists
        On Error Resume Next
        Set subFolder = currentFolder.Folders.Add(arrItem(0), arrItem(1))
        ' Discontinue error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not subFolder Is Nothing Then
            Set ActiveExplorer.currentFolder = subFolder
            Debug.Print subFolder.Name
        End If
                
    Next
     
End Sub


Public Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal parentFolder As Object, list As Variant)

    Dim subFolder As folder
    Dim arrItem As Variant
    Dim firstLevelSubfolders As Folders
    Dim previouslyCreatedParentFlag As Boolean
    
    Dim newFolder As folder
    
    Debug.Print "parentFolder: " & parentFolder
    
    Set firstLevelSubfolders = parentFolder.Folders
    
    For Each subFolder In firstLevelSubfolders
    
        Debug.Print "subFolder: " & subFolder
        
        'remove this if you only want
        '  to add the folders to the first subfolder
        LoopAllSubFolders subFolder, list
        
        previouslyCreatedParentFlag = False
        
        For Each arrItem In list
            Debug.Print arrItem(0)
            If subFolder = arrItem(0) Then
                ' This stops folders being created in previously created folders
                previouslyCreatedParentFlag = True
                
                ' To create folders in previously created folders
                ' Uncomment or 
                '  select the most deeply nested subfolder
                
            End If
        Next
        
        If previouslyCreatedParentFlag = False Then
        
            For Each arrItem In list
            
                Debug.Print arrItem(0)
                Set newFolder = Nothing
                
                ' Bypass expected error if the folder already exists
                On Error Resume Next
                Set newFolder = subFolder.Folders.Add(arrItem(0), arrItem(1))
                ' Discontinue error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not newFolder Is Nothing Then
                    Set ActiveExplorer.currentFolder = newFolder
                    Debug.Print newFolder.Name
                End If
                
            Next
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```